# Fixed parallex effect on text when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have three sections of text and I'm trying to make something like this with plain css.

[image: Example1]

```
[Link](https://codepen.io/creativeocean/pen/qBbBLyB)
```

-- This is done using gsap and svgs

[image: Example2]

```
[Link](https://codepen.io/ravid7000/pen/LREEzv)
```

I was able to do the scrolling effect when user scrolls from top to bottom the problem is if the user is on the first section, the other two sections are also visible and overlaying the first section.

[My Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-black-g443he?file=/src)

Comment: never mind i figured it out. Had to use clipt path for the wrappers.